# Android Studio: how to import Android library project

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm using Android Studio and I've never imported or referenced any external libraries before.

The library I'm trying to reference is this: https://code.google.com/p/afiledialog/

I went to File - Project Structure - Modules and added a new Module pointing to this project library. After that I have no idea how to get it to work in my app, and when following the basic info on the main page it asks me to add this to my manifest file:

```
<activity android:name="ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog.FileChooserActivity" />
```

However when I do that it reports that it cant find the package FileChooserActivity.

All help is appreciated.

EDIT: Here are the main errors:

```
Gradle: package ar.com.daidalos.afiledialog does not exist
Gradle: cannot find symbol class FileChooserDialog
Gradle: cannot find symbol class FileChooserDialog
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go back to `Project Structure` window where you added the new module. Click on your main module, go to `Dependencies` tab, click the plus icon and select `Module Dependency`.

Comment: This only works for Gradle project. What about some old projects?